# Poor performance any way of improving?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm making a app that counts how many times you have pressed a button, but at the moment the performance of my coding has been really bad, i want to when reach 5 taps disable the button immediately, but at the moment is not working, so I was thinking if you guys could give me a hand to help improve it if is possible.

Here is the code

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    private int count = 10;
    private int tap = 0;

    DispatcherTimer timerCountDown = new DispatcherTimer();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timerCountDown.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        timerCountDown.Tick += new EventHandler(timerCountDown_Tick);
        timerCountDown.Start();

    }

    //buttom counts
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        counter();
    }


    //timer
    void timerCountDown_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer();
        level();

    }


    //time remaning
    private void timer() 
    {

        txtTimerCount.Text =  "Left " + count.ToString();
        if (count > 0)
            count--;
        else
        txtTimerCount.Text = "Times Up";

        if (txtTimerCount.Text == "Times Up")
        btntap.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    //counts clicks
    private void counter() 
    {
        tap++;
        txtTimerTap.Text = "Tap Count: " + tap.ToString();

    }


    //level1
    private void level()
    {
        if (tap == 5)
            txtcomplet.Text = "Well done level completed";

        if
          (tap == 5)
            btntap.IsEnabled = false;

    }
```

Comment: Does the user only have a certain amount of time to click the button a number of times?

Comment: Which platform is this, WinForms, WPF?

Comment: Why are you using timer??

Comment: @CDSmith Looks like Windows Phone, inherits from PhoneApplicationPage

Comment: Is Windows Phone 8, and yes the users have a certain amount of time to click the button.

Comment: For this I would definitely use Reactive extensions: http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `level` method from the `counter` method instead of the tick event handler:

```
//timer
void timerCountDown_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer();
}

//counts clicks
private void counter() 
{
    tap++;
    txtTimerTap.Text = "Tap Count: " + tap.ToString();
    level();
}
```

#### Edit:

In the `level` method you can use a code block to avoid the double `if` statements:

```
private void level()
{
    if (tap == 5) {
        txtcomplet.Text = "Well done level completed";
        btntap.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Guffa, thank you very much for the help! It has improved lot! Could you explain what is the difference for me? So I can have a better understanding of my mistakes! Thanks!

Comment: @JeffersonFilho: As you were calling `level` from the tick handler, there were a delay up to a second from the click to the level check. Also, as you called `timer` first, it would always decrement the level, so you would need to get to level 6 for it to be 5 when the `level` method was called.

Comment: Oh I see! Makes sense!Thanks! So my coding is not that bad then right? Or could I improve it little bit more?

Comment: @JeffersonFilho: It's not that bad. There are some details that could be improved, like the double `if (tap == 5)` in the `levels` method.

Comment: Thanks, yeah this what I'm wondering, it can't be like that, any tips or guide that could I improve it or do it in different way? I would really appreciate

Comment: @JeffersonFilho: You can use a code block to put the two statements in the same `if` statement. I added code above.